# Make @Autowired work in an unusual Spring Boot set up

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We inherit a Spring Boot with Vaadin project. For some reason, the signature Spring annotation @Autowired isn't used in the project. I try to change the situation with the following code.

```
@Lazy
@Service
public class MyService {

  private UserService userService;

  public MyService() {
   log.debug("******** construction ****************");
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    log.debug("******** PostConstruct ****************");
    userService = ServiceAccessor.getService(UserService.class);
  }
  ...
}
```

The UserService isn't ready if the MyService is initialized during the Spring launch. As a result, I need to set it to be lazy.

In its client class, I have

```
@Autowired
private MyService service;
...
 log.debug("MyService: " + ((service == null) ? "null" : "not null"));

 service.doSome();
```

Although the debugging message shows "not null", a null point exception is thrown on the next line. I guess the "service" holds a proxy of the instance, but not a real bean. And the MyService constructor isn't called. (without @Lazy, the constructor is called during the launch). I don't know whether the cause is that the client class is outside of the Spring container or not. The client class doesn't have any Spring stereotype annotations. If yes, how do make the class be inside the Spring container? If no, any can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: It doesn't need to have spring annotations to be a bean, it has `@Autowired` and something is injected (else there wouldn't be a proxy).

Comment: ANd why not just add `@Autowired` instead of hacking a ugly accessor for the `ApplicationContext` invoked in an `@PostConstructr` so it obviously **is** a Spring managed instance you are obtaining.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something in `doSome()` that's throwing the null pointer exception? Posting the stack trace would help confirm this.